# Simulation of Claim Amounts with different lambdas for each contract

Tags: r

I am simulating claims data in R and I have used the code below before where I assumed that the number of claims were Poisson Distributed with parameter lambda and I also assumed that this lambda varies from one contract to another and hence it followed a Gamma Distribution;

```
install.packages("actuar")
library("actuar")
portfolio.1<-simul(nodes=list(contract=10,year=5),model.freq=expression(contract=rgamma(1,8),year=rpois(contract)),model.sev=expression(contract = NULL,year = rlnorm(6,1)))
sev.1 <- severity(portfolio.1)
freq.1 <- frequency(portfolio.1)
agg.1 <- round(aggregate(portfolio.1),2)
```

Now instead of using a lambda which varies (rgamma(1,8)), I wish to use a different lambda for each contract using the vector below;

```
x <- c(0.12,0.16,0.22,0.10,0.17,0.09,0.20,0.15,0.13,0.19)
```

So each lambda corresponds to each contract but I am failing to code this in R.
May you kindly assist.

Comment: You can supply `rgamma` with a vector as a shape parameter. Is what you are looking for simply `rgamma(length(x), x)` which should sample n=1 per value of `x`?

Comment: Hi Tad Dallas. Instead of using

Comment: Hi Tad Dallas. Instead of my lambda being a gamma(1,8) random variable, I want the lambda to take values from vector x which is a vector of Poisson parameters for each contract. So that rgamma should be completely out of the code. If rgamma(1,8) is replaced by 0.125 then it means that the number of claims from every contract follow a Poisson(0.125) but instead I want each contract to have its on Poisson parameter as given in vector x

Comment: So `x` is a vector of lambda values whose length is the number of contracts. You wish to draw one observation from a Poisson distribution with x lambda = x_i. Is this correct? If so, the same principle would hold as my comment above. You could use `rpois(length(x), x)` to generate a vector of length `x` of random draws from Poisson distributions with lambda values provided by elements of `x`.